How to rotate circle animatedly in flutter
I am trying to add animation in my splash screen. There are 2 circles, which are rotating like this

topright,bottomleft
topleft,bottomright
midoftopleft,midofbottomright
midofbottomleft,midoftopright

it should look like this. by circles, I meant the light color you see.
desired output
this is what I tried

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  int _currentPosition = 0;
  List<Alignment> _gradientsPositions = [
    Alignment.topRight,
    Alignment.bottomLeft,
    Alignment.topLeft,
    Alignment.bottomRight,
    Alignment.topLeft,
    Alignment.bottomRight,
  ];
  List<Color> _gradientColors = [
    AppColors.tealColor,
    AppColors.splashBlueColor ,
    AppColors.tealColor,
    AppColors.splashBlueColor ,
    AppColors.tealColor,
    AppColors.splashBlueColor ,
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (Timer timer) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = (_currentPosition + 1) % _gradientsPositions.length;
      });
      
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,

      body: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
       
          // shape: BoxShape.circle,
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: _gradientsPositions[_currentPosition],
            end: Alignment.center,
            
            colors: [
              _gradientColors[_currentPosition],
              AppColors.splashBlueColor // You can adjust the ending color as per your preference
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child:  Center(
          child: Image.asset(MediaConstants.oneLogo)
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

and this is the output.
code output

import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Animated Circles Rotation'),
    ),
    body: CircleRotationAnimation(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircleRotationAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_CircleRotationAnimationState createState() => 
_CircleRotationAnimationState();
}

class _CircleRotationAnimationState extends 
State<CircleRotationAnimation> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
late AnimationController _controller;

 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 _controller = AnimationController(
  duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
  vsync: this,
   )..repeat();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: _controller,
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 50,
            right: 50,
            child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: _controller.value * 2 * pi,
              child: _buildCircle(),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 50,
            left: 50,
            child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: _controller.value * 2 * pi,
              child: _buildCircle(),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 150,
            left: 50,
            child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: _controller.value * 2 * pi,
              child: _buildCircle(),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 150,
            right: 50,
            child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: _controller.value * 2 * pi,
              child: _buildCircle(),
               ),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       );
     },
   );
 }

 Widget _buildCircle() {
 return Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, // Change color as needed
     ),
   );
 }

@override
void dispose() {
 _controller.dispose();
 super.dispose();
 }
}


the circles are not rotating and it not exactly what it want.
